# Expect.pm - Print out subpattern groupings

Tags: perl, expect

I tried to use $expect_out(1, string) to print out sub-pattern group 1 in following example; but the program didn't take "$expect_out(1, string)". Instead it printed out (1,string) (see output below).

Any ideas on how to print out sub-pattern group 1 (which is "SunOS").

I put the parenthesis in the search pattern to indicate the group 1 for back-reference;
and internal debugging (in output) seemed to indicate that it caught the phrase correctly, but I don't know how to print it out.

Thanks,

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Expect;

my $exp = new Expect;

# Begin: 2 lines for debugging only
$exp->exp_internal(1);
$exp->log_file("./expect_log.txt");
# End: 2 lines for debugging only

$exp->spawn("uname -a");
$exp->expect(10, '-re', "^(SunOS).*") or print "\nNot found!\n";
print "$expect_out(1, string)\n";
```

---

### Output:

```
unix-machine% test_expect.pl
SunOS unix-machine 5.12 Generic_000000-00 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Bus
(1, string)
```

### Output with internal debugging on:

```
86 unix-machine% test_expect.pl
Spawned 'uname -a'
        spawn id(3)
        Pid: 25613
        Tty: /dev/pts/169
 at /home/user/PERL/lib/Expect.pm line 181
        Expect::spawn('Expect=GLOB(0x2b2040)', 'uname -a') called at test_expect.pl line 10
Starting EXPECT pattern matching...
 at /home/user/PERL/lib/Expect.pm line 561
        Expect::expect('Expect=GLOB(0x2b2040)', 10, '-re', '^(SunOS).*') called at test_expect.pl line 11
spawn id(3): list of patterns:
  #1: -re `^(SunOS).*'
```

spawn id(3): Does `'
match:
  pattern #1: -re`^(SunOS).*'? No.

SunOS unix-machine 5.10 Generic_000000-00 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Bus

spawn id(3): Does `SunOS unix-machine 5.12 Generic_000000-00 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Bus\r\n'
match:
  pattern #1: -re`^(SunOS).*'? YES!!
    Before match string: `'
    Match string:`SunOS unix-machine 5.12 Generic_000000-00 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Bus\r'
    After match string: `\n'
    Matchlist: (`SunOS')
(1, string)

Comment: Always `use strict` and `use warnings`. That way you'd have seen that the variable `$expect_out` you're outputting in `print` hasn't been declared yet.

Answer (score 2):

For quick and straight solution, use the function **$exp->matchlist** . And you may read on for some detail if you like.

"$expect_out(1, string)" works for expect scripts but not for Perl scripts, since Perl interpreter will treat $expect_out as an scalar variable and the following "(1, string)" as the original string. You may refer to the rules how Perl and PHP do with strings in double quotes for detail.

For details about how to use the Perl's Expect.pm module, please refer to CPAN:
[Expect.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.21/Expect.pod)

Enter this page and search for "brackets" you will know that **$exp->matchlist** function will do the trick.

So change your script to as:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Expect;

my $exp = new Expect;

## Begin: 2 lines for debugging only
$exp->exp_internal(1);
$exp->log_file("./expect_log.txt");
## End: 2 lines for debugging only

$exp->spawn("uname -a");
$exp->expect(10, '-re', "^(SunOS).*") or print "\nNot found!\n";
#print $expect_out(1, string);
print ${$exp->matchlist}[0],"\n";
```